# Configuring AWS Elastic Beanstalk Timezone for Auto Scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, timezone, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

I have a single instance server deployed on **AWS - Elastic Beanstalk** that needs **timezone configuration**, and I changed the timezone as logging into the EC2 environment with ssh, and update it with the linux commands listed below;

```
sudo rm /etc/localtime
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Istanbul /etc/localtime
sudo reboot
```

Everything is fine as the server is running as a single instance. The problem arose as I wanted to use Auto Scaling, Load Balancing feature. On single instance, updating the timezone on linux AMI is fine, but on **auto scaling** mode, because that the instances are created/destroyed/recreated according to the threshold metrics, all the configuration is lost.

My simple question is, how can I change/configure the timezone for an auto scalable, load balancing mode in AWS Elastic Beanstalk ?

Comment: The thing making this hard is the `sudo reboot `. I don't think you need it. There should be a way to restart the clock service. Assuming you can, you can do all this by using an ebextension config file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can configure the newly starting server with [ebextensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html).
Here's an example that works for me. Add the following command into the file `.ebextensions/timezone.config`:

```
commands:
    set_time_zone:
        command: ln -f -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Pacific /etc/localtime
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers here only managed to work for me partially (I had errors deploying when using the answers above). After some modifications, the following worked for me. I believe it has something to do with "cwd" and "permissions".

```
commands:
  0000_0remove_localtime:
    command: rm -rf /etc/localtime
  0000_1change_clock:
    command: sed -i 's/UTC/Asia\/Singapore/g' /etc/sysconfig/clock
    cwd: /etc/sysconfig
  0000_2link_singapore_timezone:
    command: ln -f -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Singapore /etc/localtime
    cwd: /etc
```

Answer (score 2):

For my first answer on StackOverflow ... I have to add new information to an excellent earlier answer.

For AWS Linux 2, Elastic Beanstalk, there is a new simple method of setting time. Add the following commands into the file .ebextensions/xxyyzz.config:

```
container_commands:
  01_set_bne:
    command: "sudo timedatectl set-timezone Australia/Brisbane"
    command: "sudo systemctl restart crond.service"
```

I'm not sure if the second command is absolutely essential, but the instances certainly play nice with it there (especially with tasks due to happen right away !).

Comment: Update 2022-02-18. "As is" didn't work. It worked when I removed 'sudo' and separated Xctl commands into different container commands.

Answer (score -1):

You can also configure it via **ssh** in the command line:

when connected to your Elastic Beanstalk Instance:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html#change_time_zone

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Montreal /etc/localtime
```

You can connect to your EB instance with the **eb** command line tool.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-cmd-commands.html

```
eb ssh
```

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that it is not sustainable.  If your Elastic Beanstalk instances are rebuilt (or your app auto-scales), the new instances will not automatically be configured and require the manual `ssh` intervention prescribed.  The `.ebextensions` answer from @tal is automatic and lives in your app's configuration.